# R Plot data frame with 4 variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I am pretty new to plotting data in R, and am a bit unsure on how to approach this. I have a df and I want to be able to plot 4 different variables and compare them to each other. Said df:

```
   process events communications     pairs non.pairs pair.ratio
1        3      5              2     18.96     17.04 1.11267606
2        3     10              2     41.73     49.27 0.84696570
3        3    100              2   1863.21   3492.79 0.53344461
4        3   1000              2 168185.50 335320.50 0.50156641
5        3      5              5     62.39     42.61 1.46421028
6        3     10              5    101.56     88.44 1.14834916
7        3    100              5   2141.60   3853.40 0.55576893
8        3   1000              5 170370.89 339174.11 0.50231101
9        3      5             10    177.21    122.79 1.44319570
10       3     10             10    248.74    186.26 1.33544508
11       3    100             10   2673.65   4466.35 0.59862080
12       3   1000             10 174205.27 345484.73 0.50423436
13       5      5              2     11.82     24.18 0.48883375
14       5     10              2     25.48     65.52 0.38888889
15       5    100              2   1120.00   4236.00 0.26440038
16       5   1000              2 100943.44 402562.56 0.25075218
17       5      5              5     40.63     64.37 0.63119466
18       5     10              5     66.91    123.09 0.54358599
19       5    100              5   1345.69   4649.31 0.28943865
20       5   1000              5 102569.10 406975.90 0.25202745
21       5      5             10    133.16    166.84 0.79812994
22       5     10             10    171.51    263.49 0.65091654
23       5    100             10   1730.58   5409.42 0.31991970
24       5   1000             10 105265.05 414424.95 0.25400268
```

There is a pattern in the df, and thus far I been able to plot the number of `events`, `communications` and `pair.ratio` against each other using:

```
g <- ggplot(data, aes(events, pair.ratio))
g + geom_point() + facet_grid(. ~ communications)
```

But I would like to add to that the number of processes.

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: Absolutely, here is a pastebin to it: http://pastebin.com/yRxRcP1n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=events, y=pair.ratio, color=as.factor(process))) +
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(. ~ communications)
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the asnwer with process converted to factor and the visual result. You can mark the answer if it satisfies you.